# How to set the default name for a user control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

Suppose that you drag a control from the toolbox and drop it on the Form in Visual Studio. It automatically selects a name to that control.

For buttons: `button1`, `button2`, ...
For labels: `label1`, `label2`, ...

As I understand, this naming is done by concatenating a default name of the control and a number.

Example for labels:

> "label" + "1", "label" + "2"

I have a custom control in which I need to set the default name given to my control automatically by the Visual Studio Designer so that my controls have the names as MyControl1, MyControl2, ... The name of the class of my control is `RoundButton`. By default, designer gives the name `roundButton1`, `roundButton2` and so on to my control. I need to change it as `rndbtn1`, `rndbtn2`, ...

I found `DefaultEvent` attribute that let me select default event opens by double clicking the control in the designer window. Is there any attribute like that to set default name or is it possible change the default name given by the designer?

**Note:** I know a name of a control can be changed from the properties window after adding the control to the form, but I need to know how to set the default name which is automatically given by the designer.

Comment: When in doubts - look into sources (e.g.  [Label](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,46), [Button](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,37), etc.). I don't know what is `DesignerAttribute` (worth to check?), but it seems names are always equal to class name with small first letter and number. I believe it's hardcoded. You have to name your class `Rndbtn` if you want designer to assign to it name like `rndbtn1`.